# Why isn't my while loop terminating? while(values[i] != -99)

Tags: c

Hi there I can't figure out why my while loop isn't terminating "while(values[i] != -99)", when I change it to == there is indeed a change in behaviour, so it's being read properly, i'm just not seeing something, thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM ((int)(sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0])))


int main(){

int values[10];
int i = 0;

printf("please enter the values you want reversed, terminate with -99\n");

while(values[i] != -99){

    for(i = 0; i<NUM ; i++){
        scanf("%d",&values[i]);
        
    }
}

for(i = NUM; i>NUM; i--){
    printf("%d",values[i]);
}

}
```

Comment: You need to learn to debug your code. Execute it on paper.

Comment: After the `for` loop, `values[i]` is outside the array bounds. Moreover, when you do manage to quit the loop early, should not be printing `NUM` values.

Comment: Tip: Don't ask for "magic numbers" to terminate, write your code so that something distinct, like a blank line will terminate it. Even better, use `argv`, that's what it's for!

Comment: Tip: Instead of the convoluted calculation in `NUM`, just `#define ENTRIES 10` and use that later: `int values[ENTRIES]`.

Comment: Why don't you check if the thing they just typed in is -99 and then abort.

Comment: try to "dry run" your code by taking small numbers and check how the inner for loop behaves and how it affects the outer while loop.

Comment: To make your code more robust you may want to consider what happens when the user enters something other than an integer (e.g., the letter 'a').

Comment: if `NUM` is defined as the number of elements in the `array value`, then the statement `for(i = NUM; i>NUM; i--)` is out of bounds on the very first iteration.  Indexing starts at zero ( `0` ) and goes through `9`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first `for` loop increments `i` until it reaches the `NUM` value. When it terminates, the `while` gets its turn and tests whether `values[i] != -99`. However, `i` is out of the array bounds at the moment (it equals `NUM` while the array's indices end at `NUM-1`), so you get undefined behavior:

- first you access a non-existing item of the array, which itself may end any way, from nothing through a crash;
- then, even if this access succeedes, you can't know what value could be read, so expecting any specific value there (e.g. `-99`) is unreasonable.

**EDIT**

Here is a possible solution,
First, entering data. Read up to `NUM` values and store them in the array. Test each value and break the loop if the 'stop' value was entered.

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM ; i++) {
    scanf("%d",&values[i]);
    if(values[i] == -99)
        break;
}
```

Then output data. If all `NUM` values were entered, `i` equals `NUM` now. If a 'stop' value of  `-99` was entered, `i` indicates the position of 'stop' in the array. Either way `i` is one past the last value, so you can simply decrement it from its current value till zero:

```
while(--i >= 0) {
    printf("%d ",values[i]);
}
```

Comment: @KevinJumpheiser Please see the expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to check what value `i` has when you end the `while` loop - because it's not reset to `0` once the `for` loop completes, but is still `10` from ending the `for` loop.

Comment: Great clue, I'm still a little confused, if I have scanned -99 into value[10] at that point, when relooping to the while loop, the value[i] should indeed have the -99 inside it at that point, and terminate? I'm still lost :P

Comment: @KevinJumpheiser It doesn't. It reloops to the for loop. After the for loop is done, then it reloops to the while loop. All the stuff inside the loop - even other loops - finishes before the loop reloops.

Comment: @KevinJumpheiser -  _"...if I have scanned -99 into value[10] at that point..."_  `value[10]` does not exist.  Indexing in `C` is zero based, therefore indexes go from `0 - 9` for something created as `int values[10];`

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear want you want to accomplish with your WHILE-loop in general. If you want the user to be able to terminate the "filling process" of `values` by entering `-99`, your code should look like this:

```
// ...
printf("Please enter the values you want reversed; terminate with -99.\n");

for (i=0;i<NUM;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&values[i]);

    if (values[i]==-99)
        break;
}
//...
```

In your code, you are filling `values` regardless of what the user enters. Then, after the user entered the new value for each element, you check the 11-th element of `values` (which does "not exist"; in other programming languages like C#, something like an IndexOutOfRangeException would be thrown). You are basically accessing memory of which you do not know the use of; this can potentially be dangerous and lead to crashes.

Also, note that your statement for printing the array content is incorrect and should be:

```
for(i=NUM-1;i>=0; i--){
    printf("%d",values[i]);
}
```

The problem is that, if you start with `i=NUM`, you are again accessing the "non existing" 11-th element of `values`. Additionally, you should be aware that `values` may not be fully filled with valid values from the user (because the user is able to terminate the "filling process" by entering `-99`).

Answer (score 0):

1. You have Undefined Behaviour as in any while loop except the first one.
2. The loops are not correct.

```
#define ARRSIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[1]))

int main()
{

    int values[10] = {0};
    size_t i = 0;

    printf("please enter the values you want reversed, terminate with -99\n");

    do
    {
        if(scanf("%d",&values[i]) != 1)
        {
            printf("SCANF error at index %zu\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }while(values[i] != -99 && ++i < ARRSIZE(values));

    for(size_t index = i; index > 0; index--)
    {
        printf("%d\n",values[index - 1]);
    }

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dq14n8

Answer (score -1):

The `while` loop does not check the `values[i]` argument until the `for` loop has completed. Try the following:

```
i=0;
while(values[i] != -99){
      scanf("%d", &values[i]);
      i=i+1;
      if (NUM == i) break;
}
```

Replacing the `while` loop currently in your code with this will ensure that the value at index `i` is checked each time.